# Why can I not save tweets into the database?

Tags: ruby, twitter, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I want to save the tweets into the database, but it doesn't work! I'm using the twitter gem.

My controller:

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

def save_tweets_into_database
    @tweets = Twitter.search("#em2012" "#Italy" "#Spain", :lang => "en", :rpp => 25).results
    @tweets.each do |tweet|
        @tweet = tweet
        @tweet.create
    end
end
end
```

My Model

```
require "rubygems"
require "twitter"


class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

My view

```
<% @title = "liste" %>
<h2>Liste der Tweets über das EM-Finale</h2>
<ul>
    <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
        <li><%= tweet %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

my routes

```
Em2012tweet::Application.routes.draw do

  match '/save_tweets', to: 'tweets#save_tweets_into_database'
end
```

This error is displayed:

undefined method `create' for Twitter::Status:0x007fac9c80a160

Rails.root: /Users/xyz/Desktop/Workspace/em2012tweet

app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:7:in `block in save_tweets_into_database'

app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:5:in `each'

app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:5:in `save_tweets_into_database'

Comment: Erm, maybe because you are not saving it into the database? I can't find a `.create` or `.save` or similiar...

Comment: Can you help me? How can I store the output?

Comment: I'd suggest you read the rails guides or buy a book first to understand how things are working in the rails world :) http://guides.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 2):

> save the tweets into the database

In Rails, following REST convention, `index` action is associated with simply displaying all the objects of a model already stored in database. And this is actually what you did with the code as well. Your `index` action isn't doing anything that will *save* the tweets into the database.

I don't think you are trying to save tweets here. You are trying to simply display them. Try this if you want to simply display tweets in index view file.

```
def index
  @tweets = Twitter.search("#em2012" "#italy" "#spain", :lang => "en", :rpp => 25).results
end
```

If you want to save tweets, create an action like this.

```
def save_tweets_into_database
  @tweets = Twitter.search("#em2012" "#italy" "#spain", :lang => "en", :rpp => 25).results
  @tweets.each do |tweet|
    Tweet.save(tweet)
  end
end
```

Comment: In which file I have to store this code? In the controller or model file?

Comment: It should be in your tweets_controller. To perform this action, you need to configure routes, so that there is a path associated with this action, `match '/save_tweets', to: 'tweets#save_tweets_into_database'`. If you go to this path in your url, 'localhost:3000/save_tweets', rails will perform `save_tweets_into_database` action and save all the tweets you grab by doing `Twitter.search("#em2012" "#italy" "#spain", :lang => "en", :rpp => 25).results`.

Comment: What I think you have to work on is duplications. My method doesn't do any work on whether or not if there are duplicate tweets being saved. That's something you'd have to work on I guess.

Comment: If I do this, I get this error message: undefined method `save' for #<Twitter::Status:0x007fc003b2ec40>

Comment: What happens if you do this. Replace `tweet.save` with this. `@tweet = tweet`, then `@tweet.save`.

Comment: It's the same error... app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:7:in `block in save_tweets_into_database',
app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:5:in `each',
app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:5:in `save_tweets_into_database'

Comment: Try `tweet.create!`. What happens then? Also, can you update your question with schema for Tweet model?

Comment: You are totally wrong. you are trying to run a active record .save method on a twitter status object. In the your each block do this
Tweet.create(tweet)

Answer (score 0):

tweets_controller.rb:

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def save_tweets_into_database
    @tweets = Twitter.search("#em2012" "#Italy" "#Spain", :lang => "en", :rpp => 25)
    @tweets.each do |tweet|
      Tweet.create(twitter_tweet: tweet)
    end
  end
end
```

tweet.rb:

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :twitter_tweet
end
```

Note that this requires you have a migration where a `tweets` table is created with a text column named 'twitter_tweet', e.g.

```
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tweets do |t|
      t.text :twitter_tweets

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow you to call `save_tweets_into_database` and save the 25 returned tweets into the database. This isn't a very good strategy, as you are serializing each of the `Twitter::Status` objects and storing them as YAML in your database. This means you lose the ability to use all the nice ActiveRecord helpers, and instead must deserialize all of the objects you want to work with before actually using them. A better strategy would be to create an ActiveRecord object that has the same attributes as those in the Twitter::Status object you wish to save. Then you can map the fetched Twitter::Status objects to the new ActiveRecord Tweet objects and retain all the benefits of using ActiveRecord.

I'll not say anything about your routing structure, other than it definitely doesn't appear to be following the 'Rails' way, which, from experience, typically leads to quite a few headaches.

Comment: How can I access the data in order to analyze, who everything was for Italy and who for Spain?

Comment: If you just want simple access to the `Twitter::Status` object, just access it like a normal ActiveRecord attribute -`Tweet.first.twitter_tweet`. This will return the `Twitter::Status` object allowing you to treat it as though it was never serialized. If you're wanting to search through the text of all the tweets, it may be better to revisit how you're storing the tweets. I can elaborate further on that if needed.